# Getting started with iOS programming

Tags: ios, ios7, programming-languages, ios-simulator, development-environment

I am qualified experienced software engineer.  Strong background in OOP/D C++, Symbian, large multi thread multi process server applications, smart phone applications.  More recently android, Java, C#, windows .net asp.net.

I am looking for 'recommendations' for a fast track entry to learning to develop in objective C and for iOS.  Looking for recommended tutorials, support communities, build tools, design tools, IDEs, and release into production process.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[http://www.amazon.com/iOS-Programming-Ranch-Edition-Guides/dp/0321942051](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321942051) this is good and also the one they did on Objective C. This is a great site too http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Comment: I learn that the new iOS language is swift but that it compiles to a binary that (assuming the features are compatible) runs on <= iOS 7.  So I am wondering is there any benefit in learning objective C or better to just start with swift only?

Comment: You should start with Objective C, Swift is a pretty young language so if you are faced with problems it will be harder to get help with as less people know the language. This is a good article: http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/ios-developers-need-to-know-objective-c/